# Select values in SQL that do not have other corresponding values except those that i search for

Tags: sql

I have a table in my database:

```
Name  |  Element
 1         2
 1         3
 4         2
 4         3
 4         5
```

I need to make a query that for a number of arguments will select the value of Name that has on the right side these and only these values.
E.g.:
arguments are 2 and 3, the query should return only 1 and not 4 (because 4 also has 5). For arguments 2,3,5 it should return 4.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT name FROM aggregations WHERE (element=2 and name in (select name from aggregations where element=3))
```

What do i have to add to this query to make it not return 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to do it:

```
SELECT name
FROM aggregations
WHERE element IN (2,3)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(element) = 2
```

If you want to add more, you'll need to change both the `IN (2,3)` part and the `HAVING` part:

```
SELECT name
FROM aggregations
WHERE element IN (2,3,5)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(element) = 3
```

A more robust way would be to check for everything that isn't not in your set:

```
SELECT name
FROM aggregations
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.element 
  FROM aggregations a
  WHERE a.element NOT IN (2,3,5)
  AND a.name = aggregations.name
)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(element) = 3
```

It's not very efficient, though.

Comment: if element is '2' and '4' it would still match both the where and the having criteria, no...?

Comment: @d: You're right, actually. This covers supersets but not subsets. Seemed to make Grin happy, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table, fill it with your values and query like this:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT name
        FROM    aggregations
        ) n
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    (
                SELECT  element
                FROM    aggregations aii
                WHERE   aii.name = n.name
                ) ai
        FULL OUTER JOIN
                temptable tt
        ON      tt.element = ai.element
        WHERE   ai.element IS NULL OR tt.element IS NULL
        )
```

This is more efficient than using `COUNT(*)`, since it will stop checking a `name` as soon as it finds the first row that doesn't have a match (either in `aggregations` or in `temptable`)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but usually I would do this with a query in my where clause for a small amount of data.  Note that this is not efficient for large record counts.

```
SELECT ag1.Name FROM aggregations ag1 
WHERE ag1.Element IN (2,3)
AND 0 = (select COUNT(ag2.Name) 
    FROM aggregatsions ag2 
    WHERE ag1.Name = ag2.Name
        AND ag2.Element NOT IN (2,3)
)
GROUP BY ag1.name;
```

This says "Give me all of the names that have the elements I want, but have no records with elements I don't want"